# Can Einstein Search to be used to prefer selected knowledge articles?

Tags: knowledge, search, einstein-search

Can Einstein Search to be used to prefer selected knowledge articles?

My customers want to have ability to have some weighting implementation to prefer some selected knowledge articles over the default search settings.

However, in Salesforce we can't really change how Search works, except maybe for Einstein Search. However, it is not clear if Einstein search might help to implement weighting